# Помогите с условием проверки пустого значения из базы данных

Tags: php, mysql

Попробовал вот таким вот образом

```
$skrit = $row['lvl'];
if ($skrit == 'NULL') { #Если в поле с уровнем пусто то выводим что скрыт
  $persoff = 'Персонаж скрыт';
}
else { #если не пусто то выводим значение из базы..
  $persoff = $row['lvl'];
}
```

Comment: А как получаете значение $row? В таблице поле lvl принимает значение NULL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Строка `'NULL'` не имеет ничего общего с "пустым значением", что бы не имелось под этим в виду.

Стандартная проверка на "пустое значение" в РНР - это просто приведение переменной к булеву типу, то есть, подстановка его в `if` напрямую

```
if ($row['lvl']) {
  $persoff = $row['lvl'];
} else {
  $persoff = 'Персонаж скрыт';
}
```

Если условие не срабатывает, то дело не в методе проверки, а в чем-то другом: кривом коде, опечатках, неверных данных в БД и т.д. Чтобы решить проблему в этом случае, надо исправлять свой код. В первую очередь смотреть, что именно находится в переменной `$row['lvl']`, ы помощью функции `var_dump()`. Если там действительно пусто - то проверять код, который идет ниже условия.

Comment: Спасибо огромное))) работает ))) теперь одной проблемой меньше)